Databricks connect from cmd
With databricks-connect==14.3.* I am not able to run a script from the command line in my venv like this
python .\my_python_file.py --environment prod --extraction_date 2024-04-24

This used to work with databricks-connect==10.4.* but now its throwing the error
RuntimeError: Only remote Spark sessions using Databricks Connect are supported. Could not find connection parameters  to start a Spark remote session.
I used to be able to run databricks-connect configure and then run commands like this, however now there is no more databricks-connect configure instead I had to use the vs code extension for databricks. Which I did and then managed to get databricks-connect test to run successfully in the same terminal. However the command above still yields said error. It seems like I should pass some argument to use a profile that I created running the command databricks auth login.

The error message you are seeing indicates that you are not using a remote Spark session with Databricks Connect. To resolve this issue, you can try passing the connection parameters to start a Spark remote session using the --jars and --driver-class-path options when running your script. Here is an example command that you can try:
python .\my_python_file.py --environment prod --extraction_date 2024-04-24 --jars /path/to/databricks-connect.jar --driver-class-path /path/to/databricks-connect.jar
